# Updating Data From MongoDB using Web API

Tags: mongodb, asp.net-web-api

I have a database that created in MongoDB using Robomongo tool. How can I update these data in Web API by its default POST, PUT, DELETE methods in ValuesControllers.cs?

Database name : StudentInfo
Collection Name : Student

```
{
  _id : ObjectId(),
  name : "lqbal",
  department : "CSE",
  phone : "0194949402"
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is an example of the `POST` Action. WebApi can perform Model binding so it can take content from the body of the `POST` action and bind it to a c# entity - in this case the `Student` object. 
Here is the content of the `Request` Body.

```
{
"name": "lqbal",
"department": "CSEGlobal",
"phone": "0194949402"
}
```

Also make sure to set the `Content-Type` of the `Reqest` to `application/json` so WebApi can perform the correct model binding.

The code in the `POST` action then has to look up the student in question in the DB. Once it retrieves the `Student` object, it can update the values and then save the object back to the DB.

```
 public void Post([FromBody]Student value)
        {
            var student = ((MongoCollection)collection).AsQueryable<Student>().First(c => c.name == value.name);
            student.department = value.department;
            student.phone = value.phone;
            collection.Save(student);

        }
```

The concept for the `PUT` action is similar to this `POST` action except that a new `Student` object is created.

The `DELETE` action is straightforward as well is similar to the `GET` action - you only need to pass the `ID` of the record to delete in the query string and then just delete it in the action controller.

Here is a link to how to remove a document with the mongo c# driver
[Mongo c# Driver - Remove an Existing Document](http://docs.mongodb.org/ecosystem/tutorial/getting-started-with-csharp-driver/#remove-an-existing-document)

Comment: I didn't get the part "just delete it in the action controller".

Comment: I've updated my answer to include a link to the Mongo documentation to show how to delete a document.